# How to customize an ISO Ubuntu 22.04 arm64 server for pre-install a .deb package

Tags: command-line, 22.04, iso, deb, customization

The situation is: I want to install a package (.deb) in the Ubuntu ISO before installing the OS, to avoid installing the package every time I use the ISO. How can I do that using the Linux command line?

Comment: If the target computers are similar enough, you can create a master system, an installed system with all the bells and whistles [prepared for OEM](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Ubuntu_OEM_Installer_Overview), make an image of it and then clone from the image to the other computers. Installed systems are rather portable, but there are problems, when some but not all computers need a proprietary kernel driver (typically for graphics or wifi). -  This is much easier that to create a custom iso file (a 'respin' of Ubuntu).

Comment: Creating a "modified Ubuntu" `.iso` would make it "NOT Ubuntu", unsupported here, and probably a TradeMark violation (IANAL).